# Icons in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I created an icon with two different image sizes in it:

- one 16x16 with 24bpp
- one 32x32 with 24bpp

using the icon editor in Visual Studio.

I had hoped that when used by a form (the Form's Icon-propery) I would see the 16x16 version in its upper left corner and the 32x32 version on the task bar. Unfortunately, the 16x16 version is used in the task bar as well.

So my question is simply: how can I persuade Windows to make a "better" choice between the differnt sizes in my icon file?

Comment: in my test it uses correct size of icon. if you change icon after setting icon property of form, try to set icon property aggain. by the way how u set icon property?

Comment: That's not a direct solution, but you may use free Gimp to combine icons of different sizes into one .ico file. Such prepared icon should work as you wish it would.

Comment: I set the Icon propery in the WinForms designer. I can combine icons of different sizes into one .ico file in Visual Studio as well. What should be the difference? 
Is there any trick with the color depths? Or in which order I stuff the different sizes in the .ico-file?

Comment: May be your taskbar less than 32 pixels in width or height?

Comment: I once wrote a small app that would combine single-image .ICO files together to make a single file with multiple sizes and bit depths, and I remember that order did matter.  If I remember right, you want biggest/best color depth first, otherwise Windows Explorer would pick the wrong image.  I know you're talking about your application rather than Windows Explorer, but it might be worth trying them in a different order.

Answer (score 3):

Import the different sized images into Gimp as layers. Make sure the larger icon is the top layer. Then you can export as .ICO and Gimp will make one file containing multiple icons.

Comment: by Making "sure the larger icon is the top layer"you are persuading Windows to make a "better" choice?

Comment: Yes. Windows expects the order to go from largest to smallest

Comment: Based on this blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101018-00/?p=12513 I'm guessing this is caused by the icon file header data incorrectly populated? At this point, I still need some experimenting to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the image in .ico file: Biggest -> Smallest.

Answer (score 0):

To have the best quality of an icon for any use, I will create the largest size. This size is 256*256. It will help you to have a better quality, except smaller size that the windows won't manage them as unique, So try to create 256' , 32' and 16' separately as images and combine them as .ico file.